# Elevation data from WMS or WMTS?

Tags: qgis, wms, dem, wmts

I am trying (I'm an absolute beginner on QGIS) to basically create a DSM from a WMS/WMTS server, in France. The french institute has several options:
https://geoservices.ign.fr/services-web-experts-altimetrie

The layer that I'm interested in is: ELEVATION.ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE.HIGHRES.MNS and the goal would be to extract the elevations for a terrain profile (we've been using the qprof plugin to do so until now, working with manually generated DEMs from aerial photos + metashape)

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: @IanTurton I'm sorry to disagree here, but there is definitely the possibility to provide elevation data via WMTS like gpsinfo.org is showing us in Austria. You can import the Austrian 1x1m DEM raster with the following WMTS description file: https://wmts.rechenraum.com/AT/DTM/getWMTSCapabilities_GDAL.xml
You will find more info here (unfortunately in German): http://gpsinfo.org/freies-wmts-hoehenservice-mit-qgis-bzw-gdal-nutzen/

Comment: it is still a **picture** of the data, you have no idea what the server has done to the underlying data before it is displayed for you.

Comment: While I agree that a WMS is an image, I am looking at a DEM served as wms on which the identify tool returns an elevation value (floating point value). This makes me wonder how this possible and whether there is a tool that can extract the values into a raster format on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

If your only goal is to create a terrain profile, maybe the geoservices REST service could be helpful here:
https://geoservices.ign.fr/documentation/services/api-et-services-ogc/calcul-altimetrique-rest

```
https://wxs.ign.fr/calcul/alti/rest/elevation.json?lon=0.2367|2.1570&lat=48.0551|46.6077&zonly=true
```

Comment: Actually I've been unclear in my request, what we need is a DSM. We need the elevation of whatever is beetween two points on a map.